# Partial application to precompute intermediary results

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

For the below quardratic formula, I have multiple `a` but `fixed` `b` and `c`.

[image]

I wish to write a `partial application` function, which execute efficiently, i.e., my function doesn't recompute fixed values (because of `b` and `c`).

---

Here is my solution

`let r b c  = let z = b *. b in fun a -> (-.b +. sqrt (z-.4.0*.a*.c))/.(a*.2.0);;`

I guess this solution can work, but I am not sure whether it is efficient enough. I just made `b^2` to be fixed as I saw other parts are all with `a`.

**Anyone can give me a better solution?**

Comment: Note that nowadays arithmetic operations are so cheap that unless you need to compute the formula a _lot_ of times, the gain will be barely noticeable. The most expensive operation is `sqrt`, which you have to compute anyway. In this case, I'd rather prefer code readability over a minor optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a correct way to deal with the situation at hand. The [alternate form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormula.html) doesn't help much (as long this obtains the accuracy you require). You may want to move the `4*c` out as well,

```
let r b c = let z = b *. b and c4 = 4.0 *. c in
            fun a -> (-.b +. sqrt (z-.a*.c4))/.(a*.2.0);;
```

Comment: You may want to look at the compiled code to see if the floats are unboxed, but it may not improve much in this case.

Comment: `let r b c = let b2 = -.b /. 2.0 and z = b2 *. b2 in fun a -> (b2 +. sqrt (z-.a*.c))/.a`